# In a proof of the representation of linear functionals of topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I'm reading the proof of the following theorem in a note on functional analysis:
 [image]

Here $p_F$ is defined as $p_F(x)=\max_{y\in F}|\langle x,y\rangle|$. Could anyone show me why the underscored sentences are true? The theorem is stated right after the definitions of dual pairs and weak topology in the chapter of locally convex spaces. I'm not sure if I'm missing something which is implicitly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *definition*, $\sigma(X,Y)$ is generated by the semi-norms $p_F$. Moreover, a linear functional $\varphi$ on a l.c.s. generated by the directed family $\mathscr P$ of semi-norms is continuous if and only if there are $p\in\mathscr P$ and $c>0$ such that $|\varphi|\le cp$.

The functional $\psi$ on $T(X)$ is *defined* by $\psi(T(x))=\varphi(x)$ -- you just have to check that this is well-defined, i.e. $T(x)=T(\xi)$ implies $\varphi(x)=\varphi(\xi)$ (which follows from $\varphi(x)=0$ if $\langle x,y_j\rangle=0$ for all $j$ applied to $x-\xi$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a reference for the result in the first paragraph? I don't see immediately why there exists $p$ and $c$ with $|\varphi|\leq cp$.

Comment: This is just the continuity at $0$: For $\varepsilon=1$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $p(x)\le \delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|\varphi(x)|\le 1$. Then you check the inequality for $c=1/\delta$ (using that $\varphi$ and $p$ are positively homogeneous).